# Determine height of screen in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, fullscreen

I have my JFrame in full screen mode using the following:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setUndecorated(true);
```

And I want to know the height. Note that Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() does not work because I'm on a Mac and the real height should exclude the height of the Mac bar thing at the top of the screen.

And in the case of Windows, for example, the height should exclude the start bar. Hence, I want to know the true height of the window space I have.

Comment: Did you try the answer from this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083410/java-screen-size-on-a-mac

Comment: *"And in the case of Windows, for example, the height should exclude the start bar."*  Not here it shouldn't.  This Windows 7 based box is configured to auto-hide the task-bar.

Comment: @nickb That's interesting, I like, but does that include the "virtual" desktop (ie multiple displays) or just a single screen??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this

```
public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds() {

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (gd != null) {

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        bounds = gc.getBounds();

        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);

        bounds.x += insets.left;
        bounds.y += insets.top;
        bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
        bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);

    }

    return bounds;

}
```

To determine the "safe" screen bounds.  This takes into consideration the screen insets and produces a rectangle of a "safe" viewable area...

**Updated**

After a little testing, I'm satisifed (as far as I have Windows with multiple screens) that `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()` seems to return the same results for the default monitor.  The benifit of the previous mention method, is it could be used to determine the "safe" bounds for any device

Credit to [Java - Screen Size on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083410/java-screen-size-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 0):

frame.getContentPane().getHeight();

When you use this method, you get the height of the JFrame, not the screen. It also excludes the border heights.